# Keras : using generators to output trainingset batches and targets but also auxiliary data not used for training

Tags: keras, generator

I need to use generators (because of too large datasets) to yield training data and targets to a CNN for training. However, each data sample is normalized (/maxVal) and I need to un-normalize/de-normalize it just before the loss function. I don't know how to output this auxiliary data at the same time as a batch of (X,Y) from the generator?

It is something very similar to https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-data-generators-and-how-to-use-them-b69129ed779c :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence


class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    """Generates data for Keras
    Sequence based data generator. Suitable for building data generator for training and prediction.
    """
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, image_path, mask_path,
                 to_fit=True, batch_size=32, dim=(256, 256),
                 n_channels=1, n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        """Initialization
        :param list_IDs: list of all 'label' ids to use in the generator
        :param labels: list of image labels (file names)
        :param image_path: path to images location
        :param mask_path: path to masks location
        :param to_fit: True to return X and y, False to return X only
        :param batch_size: batch size at each iteration
        :param dim: tuple indicating image dimension
        :param n_channels: number of image channels
        :param n_classes: number of output masks
        :param shuffle: True to shuffle label indexes after every epoch
        """
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.labels = labels
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.mask_path = mask_path
        self.to_fit = to_fit
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dim = dim
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        """Denotes the number of batches per epoch
        :return: number of batches per epoch
        """
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Generate one batch of data
        :param index: index of the batch
        :return: X and y when fitting. X only when predicting
        """
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X = self._generate_X(list_IDs_temp)

        if self.to_fit:
            y = self._generate_y(list_IDs_temp)
            return X/np.max(X), y/np.max(y)
        else:
            return X

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """Updates indexes after each epoch
        """
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def _generate_X(self, list_IDs_temp):
        """Generates data containing batch_size images
        :param list_IDs_temp: list of label ids to load
        :return: batch of images
        """
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = self._load_grayscale_image(self.image_path + self.labels[ID])

        return X

    def _generate_y(self, list_IDs_temp):
        """Generates data containing batch_size masks
        :param list_IDs_temp: list of label ids to load
        :return: batch if masks
        """
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            y[i,] = self._load_grayscale_image(self.mask_path + self.labels[ID])

        return y

    def _load_grayscale_image(self, image_path):
        """Load grayscale image
        :param image_path: path to image to load
        :return: loaded image
        """
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = img / 255
        return img
```

Comment: Can you show your code so that we can have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I will try to show something but i cannot show everything unfortunately due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: it is very similar to : https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-data-generators-and-how-to-use-them-b69129ed779c

Comment: With the code you gave, I find it a bit difficult to see where your data is normalized (are your samples alreay normalized when you load them from the disk) and where you would want to de-normalize them. Furthermore, to de-normalize your data, you need to know the original mean and standard deviation, do you have this information?

Comment: yes sorry -  i added return X/np.max(X), y/np.max(y) which is what I would do

Comment: and you see, I need to be able to output the max for each X and Y, and at some point just before the loss function, denormalize them

Comment: What do you call "just before the loss function"? Moreover, it is not recommended to normalize your data the way you are doing it. You should fit a scaler on your whole dataset (for example a MinMaxScaler). Sklearn's implementation allows you to `inverse_transform` your data, which is convenient in your case.

Comment: I mean that in fact the loss function should compare both un-normalized X,Y but be trainied on normalized data (so that it can be in the rage 0,1 or -1,1. "Just before" would in fact be the output layer

Comment: oh then I might use this MinMaxScaler to normalized and to denormalize if it can memorize the normalizing values perhaps in some way? Oh no it's part of sklearn lib, I though a function of the Keras library which could do the norm/unnorm process in a transparent manner

Answer (score 0):

So, if I have understood your need correctly, what you need to do:

1. Fit a `MinMaxScaler` on your whole target (y) dataset (if possible)
2. For each batch

   1. Scale your batch's targets
   2. Yield your batch's targets
3. Create a custom loss function that takes your scaler as an argument
4. Call your scaler's `inverse_transform` on your `y_true` and `y_pred` in your custom loss
5. Call your favorite loss function on your de-normalized `y_true` and `y_pred` and return its value

Comment: Sounds almost like what i m looking for but: the training data (x) also has to be normalized for the network to learn in the normalized domain, and I don't understand how the inverse_transform will know how to de-normalize my y_true and y_pred ? Can Keras store that in a sort of auxiliary variable not used for training? or is it something else? (because in reality each training example will have a different max, these are not going to be images between 0 and 255, its something else...)

Comment: You have to use two scalers: one for you samples and one for your targets. I only included what had to be done for the targets as I don't see why you would want to de-normalize your samples as they are not used to compute the loss.

Comment: yes sure I don't need to de-normalize the samples, that's correct, but they have to be normalized and then the y_pred must be de-normalized with the same max values don't you agree? What I don't understand is how/where you store these max values, used for de-normalising - for each y_pred,y_true?

Comment: what about the "storage" ?